# How to pass textbox value by ServerSide datatable ajax call in MVC5

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax

I have a server side data-table.

When I make an `ajax` call, it does not send the given value in the text-box, it sends empty.

When I pass static data it's working fine.

This is fine:

```
 var table = $("#tblUsers").DataTable({
            "language":
            {
                "processing":
                    "<div class='overlay custom-loader-background'><i class='fa fa-cog fa-spin custom-loader-color'></i></div>"
            },
            "processing": true,
            "serverSide": true,    
            "ajax":
            {
                "url": "/Client/GetData",
                "type": "POST",
                "dataType": "JSON",
                'data': ({ ZoneID: zoneIDs })
            },                
            "columnDefs": [
                {
                    "targets": [0],
                    "width": "5%",
                    "hidden": true,
                }
            ],
            "fnRowCallback": function (nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
                //console.log(nRow);
                $(nRow).find("td:eq(0)").attr("hidden", true);
                return nRow;
            },    
            "columns": [
                {
                    "data": "ClientDetailsID"
                }]
        });
```

But when I pass `zoneid` from textbox value instead of static data it sends empty.

```
"data": { ZoneID: $("#txtSOmething").val() }
```

Comment: Can you add your HTML and JS code here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `data` to

```
data: function(d){
    d.myValue = $("#txtSOmething").val();
}
```

The on the server look for myValue in the `Request`. For example, asp mvc: `Request.Form.Get("myValue")`

Comment: The value can also be fetched like `Request.QueryString["myValue"]`